# Javascript dictionary with dot in the key

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary

I want create a dictionary in javascript, one of the key being stored in an environment variable. I want to do something like this:

```
const plop = { process.env.PLOP: "plop" }
```

however it seems invalid:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

Any idea how I could make this valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need [`computed property names`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)**:

```
const plop = { [process.env.PLOP]: "plop" }
```

**For a wider compatibility (if necessary):**

```
var plop = {};
plop[process.env.PLOP] = 'plop';
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using ES6 syntax (noticed the usage of `const`), you can use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015):

```
const plop = { [process.env.PLOP]: "plop" }
```